# PowerShell script run by a scheduled task wont launch the browser

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-desktop, browser, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task that run everytime a user connect via RDP session (RDPcoreTS Operational log - event id 98)

I have set up the task to use that event ID as trigger and for action i have set up the followign script to launch:

```
Set-Location -Path c:\DokuWikiStick\server

start-process .\mapache.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

start-process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' "http://localhost:8800"
```

The task fires correctly as mapache.exe is launched everytime  a RDP session is opened. However, the browser is never launched.

Why is this? How can I get the browser to launch as well?

The script works because when i execute the script without the scheduled task everything works as expected and browser opens. However, when it is run by the scheduled task the browser wont open yet the other parts of the script do run

Any suggestions?

Comment: PowerShell notwithstanding, you cannot launch a GUI app, that is not executed in a logged-on user context. If you have not set the task to run only when the user is logged on, it is supposed to fail by design. PowerShell runs in the user context who launched it.

Comment: ah that makes sense of course. How do I make it launch so that it opens the browser for any user that logs on

Comment: There is a checkbox for that in the [GUI 'Run Only When User is Logged On'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2r1b.png), and of course, you can set that in code.

Comment: @postanote but wouldn't that mean that the task only runs when that particular user log in. Will it run if any user logs in?

Comment: No, that is for any user.

Comment: @sukhvir Yes, you are absolutely correct, if you select 'Run only when use is logged on' and you have an explicit credential it is running as, then it will only run when that user logs on (not any user). If you run it whether user is logged on or not, you will not see what's run as the logged on user. You'll have to do this a little differently I believe to get it to work for your needs. A simple solution might be to have a startup script in the Windows startup folder that confirms the process is running, waits 5 seconds and then launches. There are other ways too so just quick thoughts.